# java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: cacheList

Tags: java, struts2

Now, I'm coding a program with struts 2.8 version; when I set the devMode in struts.xml file as follows

```
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
```

the program throws a Exception:

```
Throwable occurred: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: cacheList
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFieldImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Class.java:517)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.LocalizedTextUtil.clearMap(LocalizedTextUtil.java:835)
```

,I know when set the value="false",the Exception will not occur. But I want to solve this bug. Who can help me ? thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the `devMode` documentation, When enabled, Struts 2 will reload your resource bundles, configuration files and struts.xml on every request. Perhaps this setting which is less widely known, and therefore a source of much confusion: it will **raise the level of debug or normally ignorable problems to errors**. For example: when you submit a field which cannot be set on an action 'someUnknownField'(**cacheList in your case**), it will normally be ignored. However, when you're in development mode, an exception will be thrown, telling you an invalid field was submitted. This is very useful for debugging or testing large forms, but can also be confusing if you're relying on parameters in your request that are not set on the action, but which you are using directly in your view layer (warning: bad practice, you should always validate input from the web).Hope this clarifies why the error is thrown when devMode is enabled.